# How to simulate simultaneous touch in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I currently have two buttons on my screen , one on the left and one on the right , I wanted to know if there is a way in the `iOS Simulator` to simulate both buttons being pressed at the same time. I tried pressing <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> on the simulator as a result two circles appear. I can position one circle to the first button on the left however I am not sure how to position the next circle on the right button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have the two circles (using the Alt key), move the circles together, then hold the shift key: this will allow you to move the two circles anywhere on the simulator screen.

Then let go the key and click.

I just tried it with this code:

```
-(void)tapTwo:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    CGPoint p1 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
    CGPoint p2 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:1 inView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Points: %@ and %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(p1),NSStringFromCGPoint(p2));
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer* r = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapTwo:)];
    r.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:r];
}
```

and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For the two Circles, all you need to do is click windows + alt button together and to move those two circles to desired position you need to press shift button and drag your cursor to that position.
(The solution is for windows keyboard)